# Openlayers 4 vector map

Tags: vector, openlayers

I'm creating a dashboard site and I'm using a vector layer to select a wards (in this prototype I'm using ESSEX UK with all the wards inside, see image)

[image]

and this is the code I'm using.

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html?q=selec

the problem is that when I create the geojson file from a map file (the only field inside the map file is the ward name and the code,not too much info) the size start to be a bit big for just this piece of map and is pretty slow to load the map and once I tried to load a bigger file (almost 6mb) and Openlayers fails to load it, now I need to create another prototype but for the whole UK (just regions, no wards).

which format are supported from OL4 to vector? can I achieve something like this with another format that is not GeoJson?

I need to be able to click and get back at least the name of where I'm clicking and use it to launch my other function that needs the name to works.

Comment: You can try using vector tiles. https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/

Comment: I can't use external services, we have our own dedicated server with mapserver

Comment: You don't have to use an external service if you can generate your own vector tiles. I'm not familiar with mapserver but you can check these links. http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-119.html https://medium.com/tantotanto/vector-tiles-postgis-and-openlayers-258a3b0ce4b6

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to address the performance problems of client side rendering of vector data.

First of all, it's a bit weird that you can't render 6mb of vector data with openlayers. In my experience (mostly with OpenLayers 2), 6mb isn't that much. However, it heavily depends on client capabilities.
What's the problem with loading? Timeout? Freeze? Unresponsive pan/zoom?

You could render data server side, using WMS or tiles. You could use mapserver or geoserver for example. Then, to select objects, you could use a GetFeatureInfo request.

Otherwise, as suggested by pavankguduru, you could try with the vector tiles format.

Probably, your vector data is too "detailed" for your purposes. You could simplify them to reduce the number of points of each geometry. See GRASS's v.generalize tool.

You could also use an aggregate version of your data (regions) until the user zoom in.

IMHO, if your application needs to run on old browsers/PC, then you need to render server-side.

Comment: Could be that was too detailed, I removed all the info from the map and left just the ward_name and the area_code, and from 12 Mb I reduce to 6 but still it takes around 5 second to draw the map.
I can't use external services as we have our dedicated server with mapserver. I will see if I can simplify the geometry :)